# How to download file from external api response source using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I need to download files from an api response source using Laravel.

A sample api - (http://webservice.test.de/merchants/orders/getOrderInvoice?key=1234567894&format=json&order_no=444555666.

After calling this API I will get a JSON response. JSON response is given below.

```
{
    "result": {
        "success": "1",
        "invoice": {
            "src": "webservice.test.de/docs/invoice?secure_key=333444555666777888&key= 1234567894",
            "filename": "Invoice_12345-234566.pdf"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this src url (`['result']['invoice']['src']`) on browser, a pdf file (`Invoice_12345-234566.pdf`) will download. How can I download file from `src` using Laravel?

**Laravel code**

```
public function curl($url) 
{
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 $jsonDecodedResults = json_decode($result, true);
 return $jsonDecodedResults;
}

$getOrderInvoice = 'http://webservice.test.de/merchants/orders/getOrderInvoice?key=1234567894&format=json&order_no=444555666';

$jsonDecodedResults = $this->curl($getOrderInvoice);

if( $jsonDecodedResults['result']['success'] === '1' ) {

     $fileSource = $jsonDecodedResults['result']['invoice']['src'];
     $fileName = $jsonDecodedResults['result']['invoice']['filename'];
     $headers = ['Content-Type: application/pdf'];
     return response()->download($fileSource, $fileName, $headers);

}
```

**Error**
`exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException"`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The sample url you provided is not working, if it's just a dummy thenmy bad, otherwise you don't need to run the CURL, you can get the file by file_get_contens() function. then save the file in your local and serve it as download response.

Comment: @BlackXero. Given urls are dummy.

Comment: Are you creating the file using some package like TCPDF? If so I have a suggestion like , Save the file into a server directory and download that from a that saved directory (For downloading from a directory path , there are several methods available using php ) Thank you :)

Comment: @Ajith. Not using any packages. File source is getting from external api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved.

I have used `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` built in function to get and store contents from api resource. Functionality is running fine now.

```
// URL src and Filename from API response
$fileSource = $jsonDecodedResults['result']['invoice']['src'];
$fileName   = $jsonDecodedResults['result']['invoice']['filename'];
$headers = ['Content-Type: application/pdf'];

$pathToFile = storage_path('app/'.$fileName);
$getContent = file_get_contents($fileSource); // Here cURL can be use.
file_put_contents( $pathToFile, $getContent ); 
return response()->download($pathToFile, $fileName, $headers);
```

OR

We can use curl `$getContent = $this->curl($fileSource);` instead of `$getContent = file_get_contents($fileSource);`

```
public function curl($url) 
{
 //create a new cURL resource
 $ch = curl_init();

 // TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it directly.
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 // set url and other appropriate options
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

 // grab url and pass it to the browser
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 // close cURL resouces, and free up system resources
 curl_close($ch);

 $jsonDecodedResults = json_decode($result, true);

 return $jsonDecodedResults;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not completely sure of what you are trying to do, but I would recommend using [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) to send an `HTTP` request to an external `API`. It is easy to [install](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/overview.html#installation) using `composer` on your `Laravel` application.

As it is explained in [Using Responses](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#using-responses) you can access your response `body` (in this case the `contents` of a `.pdf` file) like this:

```
$body = $response->getBody();
// Explicitly cast the body to a string
$stringBody = (string) $body;
```

and then you can use the [Laravel File System](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem) to store the file on your local storage doing something like this:

`Storage::disk('local')->put('Invoice_12345-234566.pdf', $stringBody);`

As it is explained in [The Local Driver](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-local-driver).

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution i was using in my case.

You should download external image using copy() function, then send it to user in the response:

```
 $fileSource = $jsonDecodedResults['result']['invoice']['src'];
 $headers = ['Content-Type: application/pdf'];

 $tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $fileSource);
 copy(**YOUR_TEMP_Directory**, $tempFile);
 return response()->download($tempFile, $fileName, $headers);
```